# ET035009DH6 lcd display config

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, u-boot, lcd, imx6

The display (ET035009DH6) stays dark with the following configuration. The backlight is on. Touch is working.
[ETM035009EDH6 Spec](https://www.glynshop.com/erp/owweb/Daten/DSS/EDT/Products/Specifications/Active%20Displays/ETM035009EDH6.pdf)

- Toradex Colibri iMX6ULL 512MB V1.1A
- Toradex Colibri Evaluation Board Rev. 3.2
- ET035009DH6
- angstrom-lxde-image

Device Tree

```dts
lcdif@021c8000 {
    compatible = "fsl,imx6ul-lcdif", "fsl,imx28-lcdif";
    reg = <0x021c8000 0x00004000>;
    interrupts = <0x00000000 0x00000005 0x00000004>;
    clocks = <0x00000001 0x000000a2 0x00000001 0x000000a1 0x00000001 0x00000000>;
    clock-names = "pix", "axi", "disp_axi";
    status = "okay";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <0x0000003f 0x00000040>;
    display = <0x00000041>;
    lcd-display {
        bits-per-pixel = <0x00000010>;
        bus-width = <0x00000012>;
        linux,phandle = <0x00000041>;
        phandle = <0x00000041>;
        display-timings {
            native-mode = <0x00000042>;
            320x240 {
                phandle = <0x00000042>;
                linux,phandle = <0x00000042>;
                clock-frequency = <0x00632ea0>;
                hactive = <0x00000140>;
                vactive = <0x000000f0>;
                hback-porch = <0x00000044>;
                hsync-len = <0x00000058>;
                hfront-porch = <0x00000014>;
                vback-porch = <0x00000012>;
                vsync-len = <0x00000016>;
                vfront-porch = <0x00000004>;
                hsync-active = <0x00000000>;
                vsync-active = <0x00000000>;
                de-active = <0x00000001>;
                pixelclk-active = <0x00000000>;
            };
            640x480 {
                clock-frequency = <0x018023d8>;
                hactive = <0x00000280>;
                vactive = <0x000001e0>;
                hback-porch = <0x00000028>;
                hfront-porch = <0x00000018>;
                vback-porch = <0x00000020>;
                vfront-porch = <0x0000000b>;
                hsync-len = <0x00000060>;
                vsync-len = <0x00000002>;
                de-active = <0x00000001>;
                hsync-active = <0x00000000>;
                vsync-active = <0x00000000>;
                pixelclk-active = <0x00000000>;
            };
            800x480 {
            };
            800x480pixclkact {
            };
            800x600 {
            };
            1024x600 {
            };
            1024x768 {
            };
    };
```

U-Boot

```sh
setenv vidargs video=mxsfb:320x240M-18@60
```

When connecting a screen via VGA to the Eval Board (Toradex Colibri Evaluation Board Rev3.2) and leave the default LCD timings to 640x480 (`phandle` and `linux,phandle` in 640x480) the screen shows the LXDE desktop.

Comment: Hey, I work for Toradex. Can you post this in our community forum with more details on the SW you are using? https://www.toradex.com/community/ Thanks!

If you are using the direct RGB connection, you should be able to see an image at least with our default BSP 2.8b7 and/or Toradex Easy Installer. Mind trying that and see if you get an image?

Comment: Also some extra info:

https://developer.toradex.com/knowledge-base/display-output-resolution-and-timings-linux#iMX_6ULL_and_iMX_7_based_modules
Some tips: do NOT ever use -18, try with pixclockpol=1 as well. What is fbset reporting in the bootlog/dmesg?